# Java NoClassDefFoundError error on enum

Tags: java, noclassdeffounderror

I have an error in my application.

Here is a bit of code of my class CLog :

```
enum eType {
    IN,
    OUT,
};
public void function1(String sParams)
{
    _log(sParams, eType.IN);
}
```

This class is compiled in .jar.

When I call *function1* from my app, I get error **NoClassDefFoundError** :

```
02-28 17:08:53.853: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(880): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Clog.eType
```

I don't understand why enum is not found while function1 (class method) is found.

Comment: Hi, what are you doing in _log? Is that in a separate class / .jar file? What is it's signature?

Comment: @Srinivas Reddy Thatiparthy How can I extend scope ? This enum is used only in this class byt _log function which is a mthod of my class CLog

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Chances are you've included `CLog.class` in your apk/jar, but not `CLog$eType.class`, which is the file that represents the `CLog.eType` class.

(It would be worth trying to follow Java naming conventions, by the way - which *don't* include "C for class" and "E for Enum".)

Comment: Yes, you're right, I didn't get all .class in my .jar. Thanks a lot for your help !